# How do I create AND/OR within INDEX(SMALL(IF based off of multiple criteria or only a couple criteria based on user input?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The current problem that I'm facing is, I have three drop down options, `Race`,`Category`,`Level` within each have different classifications. For this example the classifications are as follows for the list:

```
Race      Category        Level
Druid    Transmutation    Cantrip
Cleric    Abjuration      Level 1
          Conjuration     Level 2
```

Again for clarification these are 3 items are just a list for the user to select from. Currently I'm able to have the user select `Race` and `Category` to show all information for that given `Race` and `Category`. But, if the user wants to only use `Race` and `Level` or `Race` and `Category` and `Level` that is the part I'm having trouble with in creating an array that would work correctly with it.

The first sheet in this example looks like this:
[image: Sheet1]
As you can see, the current code works perfect for the `Race` and `Category` selection. The code looks like:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$H,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$1,Sheet2!$A:$A)*COUNTIF($E$1,Sheet2!$B:$B),ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H))+1),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

The Lookup Tab looks like the following:
[image: Lookup Tab]

I have tried a few various ways of trying to let the User choose `Race` and `Category` and `Level` / `Race` and `Category` / `Race` and `Level` but with no luck, either giving me a blank (Due to the `IFERROR` statement I have or giving me just the titles of each column. The codes I have tried look like:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$H,SMALL(IF(AND(COUNTIF($C$1,Sheet2!$A:$A),OR(COUNTIF($E$1,Sheet2!$B:$B),COUNTIF($G$1,Sheet2!$D:$D))),ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H))+1),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

And:

```
{=IFERROR(OR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$H,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$1,Sheet2!$A:$A)*COUNTIF($E$1,Sheet2!$B:$B),ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H))+1),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$H,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$1,Sheet2!$A:$A)*COUNTIF($G$1,Sheet2!$D:$D),ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H))+1),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$H,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$1,Sheet2!$A:$A)*COUNTIF($E$1,Sheet2!$B:$B)*COUNTIF($G$1,Sheet2!$D:$D),ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A:$H))+1),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1))),"")}
```

But both do not work of what I'm trying to achieve.

The end result that I am looking for, is to have the User be able to choose `Race` and `Category` and `Level` / OR `Race` and `Category` (Leaving `Level` blank) / OR `Race` and `Level` (Leaving `Category` blank) That way the User can control how they want to see the information they want instead of being tied down to only `Race` and `Category`.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

-Maykid

Comment: This would work better with an advanced filter.

Comment: @ScottCraner Do you mean in terms of a Pivot Table instead of an array formula?

Comment: No, use Advanced Filter.  It is on the data tab.  There are plenty of tutorials on the web how to use it.